# How to validate movable(portable) application

Tags: spring, validation, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm having trouble with validating one movable app. 
When I open the app and fill-up the data, I send this data to the controller. Then validate this data and if any error I wan to show this error on the app without close it. If no error, I proceed to the success page and close the app. So far I manage to create the app and to validate the data, but my problem is that I don't know how to redirect from the controller back to the add without close it and show this error. 
My web application is using Spring. 
Here is some of my code: 
This is how I init my index page:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView initializeForm(ModelMap model){
    ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("index.jsp");
    result.addObject("loginInfo", new LoginInfo());
    return result;
}
```

This is what happen when submit the data from the movable app:
Here I wan when there is an error, to redirect to the same app without close it.
        @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("loginInfo") @Valid LoginInfo logInfo,
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model){

```
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "";//here I need to redirect to the movable app form.
    }

    return "redirect:login.htm";    
}
```

Here is my jsp:

```
    <form:form action="welcome" method="GET" id="mainLogForm" commandName="loginInfo">  
    <div id="loginForm" class="ui-widget-content" >
          <table align="right" width="300" cellpadding="0">
            <tr><td align="right"><input type="button" id="cancelButton" value="x" onclick="showHide('loginForm')"/></td></tr>
          </table>
          <table align="center" width="300" bgcolor="f8f8ff" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" >
            <tr>
              <td align="right" width="100">User:</td>
                <td width="100"><form:input path="username" /></td>
                <td width="100"><form:errors path="username" cssClass="error"/></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td align="right" width="100">Password:</td>
                <td width="100"><form:input path="password" type="password"/></td>
                <td width="100"><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/></td>
             </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" id="logInButton" align="center" value="SignIn" onclick="submitForm()" />
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by movable. Take a look at this: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Comment: By movable application I mean application like the ones on twitter when U click on some user link. It's like pop-up windows but it's part of the same page. And my problem is that when I click the submit button from this app to submit the log-in data, I wan the controller to show the error messages to this app without closing it.